# Can the Google Ads identify my phone for ads in apps?

Tags: google, ads

A lot of free apps rely on advertisement. Even the OS in a lot of mobiles show ads in built-in utility applications.

Does the Google Ads framework has a capability to identify an Android user for the ad shown in the following scenarios?

1. Ad shown in an app where Google log in credentials have been used.
2. Ad shown in an app where Google log in credentials haven't been used, but the app's data and cache is intact.
3. Ad shown in an app where Google log in credentials haven't been used and the app's data and cache have been cleared.

Comment: [Definitely yes](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/11416267?hl=en&visit_id=637934562782452789-2600070456&p=data-safety&rd=1#zippy=%2Cdata-collection%2Cdata-sharing%2Cdata-types) for the first case (see "Types of data & collection purposes covered in the Data safety section") and by extension in other two cases (less Google credentials because user hasn't signed - in)